# how to parse this json using jquery ajax and set all value to autocomplete in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to parse this json and set all the message valur to a input type autocomplete in codeigniter.

```
{
  "status": true,
  "message": ["9876421234", "6544545454", "5454365765", "4546466554", "5656565654", "5656565654", "785687878", "565654", "7676576565", "6676766665", "544443", "767", "1232323221", "9540441411", "6677686765", "8987876554"]
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As first please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt match your criteria.

Comment: You can easily get messages like `var obj = JSON.parse(jsonstring); var msgs = obj.message`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like:

var str='{"status": true,"message": ["9876421234", "6544545454", "5454365765", "4546466554", "5656565654", "5656565654", "785687878", "565654", "7676576565", "6676766665", "544443", "767", "1232323221", "9540441411", "6677686765", "8987876554"]} ';
console.log(str);

var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj.message[0],obj.message[1],obj.message[2]);